# Term Reference field as checkboxes, not auto-complete?

Tags: entities, taxonomy-terms

I have a brand new Drupal 8 installation (my first D8 site). I've created a new content type with a Term Reference field.

When adding content, it appears that the only way to select a term is via type ahead, auto-complete. Instead, I need a simple list of terms with checkboxes.

I can't recall struggling with this in D7 before. Is there a module I should install... or setting that I should configure?

Comment: When you add fields to a content type the widget settings are in a separate tab "Manage form display". I think in D7 field settings and widgets were in the same tab.

Comment: Yes! This is the answer! Very different from D7. Please submit as an answer and I'll mark as the solution. Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To change the tag selection to check boxes configure the widget in the tab *Manage form display*:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

There is a D8 version of [Term Reference Tree](https://www.drupal.org/project/term_reference_tree) that works great for this.  Especially if you have a hierarchical term layout.